# In sails dynamically change what to populate and use connection?

Tags: javascript, orm, sails.js, waterline

Well consider a function inside a controller as below:

```
test_func: async function(id, update_vals, connection=undefined) {
    if (connection !== undefined) {
        await Data.update({id: id}, update_vals).usingConnection(connection);
    } else {
        await Data.update({id: id}, update_vals);
    }
}
```

I have to create an if statement, based on wether or not we are using the function inside a transaction. This becomes even worse when we add another flag "fetch" to the list. Suddenly there are 4 cases and each need its own if statement due to the syntax requirements.

Or in a place where it becomes even impossible: a function that gets data and populates based on an input list:

```
get_test_func: async function(id, populated_list) {
    if (populated_list.length === 0) {
        return Data.find({id: id}).populate(populated_list[0]);
    } else if (populated_list.length === 1) {
        return Data.find({id: id}).populate(populated_list[0])
                                  .populate(populated_list[1]);
 ......
```

Can these additions to the query (db connection & populate specially) be moved inside the query?